# Extracting RGB values from aerial photo and assigning to LAS file with FME?

Tags: fme-form, lidar, imagery, las, rgb

I need to extract the RGB Values from imagery and assign to a .las file in order to display 3d landscape with "real" colours. I have an unlicenced LAStools, FME 2017 and ArcGIS 10.3.1 at hand.

I have tried with `las2las`, but the tools don't take the option `--color-source` as was documented in [liblas.org](https://www.liblas.org/utilities/las2las.html#). With FME I can visualize this effect but not export to .las.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the PointCloudOnRasterComponentSetter transformer in FME. Check out this tutorial: https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/1096/color-and-point-clouds.html

Answer (score 3):

This functionality was removed from libLAS and moved over to [PDAL](https://pdal.io). The filter you want to use is called `filters.colorization`, and it allows you to control how the bands map to the color values of the LAS file in addition to other useful switches.

See the [`filters.colorization`](https://www.pdal.io/stages/filters.colorization.html) documentation for how to use the filter. See the PDAL [QuickStart](https://www.pdal.io/quickstart.html) for how to use Docker to run PDAL command line applications on Windows if that is your platform to run upon.

An example PDAL pipeline for colorization would specify `filters.colorization` attributes like the following:

```
{
    "pipeline":[
    "uncolored.las",
    {
        "type":"filters.colorization",
        "dimensions":"Red:1:1.0, Blue, Green::256.0",
        "raster":"aerial.tif"
    },
    "colorized.las"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is an updated example. https://pdal.io/workshop/exercises/analysis/colorization/colorization.html